# D3 different zoom factor on each axis

Tags: d3.js, zooming, non-linear

I am trying to figure out how to create different zoom factors on the X- and Y-axis in d3. It seems to be created with a single zoom-factor for both axis, and basically I would like to know if there is a way to separate them.

The basics is simple enough: There is excellent support in d3 for an even zoom-effect on x- and y-axises. It is also easy to turn off the zoom for one axis. But I cant find a way to create this intermediate effect. The goal is to have the y-axis zoom 10 times more than the x-axis for each mouse wheel zoom-event.

I have no actual code to show, since I dont know if it is possible. Perhaps a useful hint, is that I work with D3 version 5. The usual, more or less standardized zoom code is used.